# solution of polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials

so dear community, here is my second question.

assume we have a system, where

$A_1 x + B_1 y = C_1 $

$A_2 x^2 + B_2 y^2 = C_2 $

$A_3 x^3 + B_3 y^3 = C_3 $

etc.

can this system be solved?

if yes, i would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The first two equations determine your $x, y$ up to finite indeterminacy, so your system is generally overdetermined. To solve the first two equations, the quadratic formula works well.

Comment: the quadretic formula works only upto degree 2, if i am correct. what happens if the system is like

$A_1 x + B_1 y +  ... + Z_1 z$

$A_2 x^2 + B_2 y^2 +  ... + Z_2 z^2$

$A_m x^m + B_m y^m +  ... + Z_m z^m$

i.e. what happens if there is a system n variables and up to degree m ?

comment . please do not misunderstand me, but  would anyone ask a question in mathoverflow, if that was solvable by just quadratic formula. would they not just go to yahoo clever? 

also, although i used only up to degree 2 in the example, i was looking for a general way to solve this type of equations.

Comment: @Sean: Ask the question you want answered. If you cannot use proper mathematical notation, MO is not for you. Finally, look up Newton's identities.

Comment: @Felipe: that will teach me to not just close it...